# Check if list value is in string but not values within other list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
list = ['for','and','with','be in']
```

And I have implemented some code that checks to see if the above words are contained within a string:

```
if any(word in stringVar for word in list):
   \\logic
```

The above works as expected, however, I wan't to have some phrases excluded from the above as follows:

```
exc_list = ['for every','for each']
```

So essentially, I want to change my if statement so that it returns true if `and`, `with` and `be in` are contained within the `stringVar` OR `for` is contained within the `stringVar` but not when it is followed by `every` or `each`.

I had originally implemented this:

```
if any(word in stringVar for word in list) and any(word not in stringVar for word in exc_list):
   \\logic
```

But this will not work as expected if the `stringVar` is equal to 'will be in every day for each week'.

To confirm, I want to return true at all times when `and`, `with` and `be in` are contained within the `stringVar`, even if `for each/every` is to appear too. The exclusions should only come into effect when `for` appears within `stringVar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a replaced string, removing all exclusions in the replacement.

That way you know your exclusions aren't in the string and can just directly check for items you care about.

```
string = 'will be in every day for each week'
lst = ['for','and','with','be in']
exclusions = ['for every','for each']

replaced_string = string
for phrase in exclusions:
    replaced_string = replaced_string.replace(phrase, '')
if any(word in replaced_string for word in lst):
    # do stuff
```

You could even place it in a function to make it look nicer.

```
def string_minus_exclusions(string, exclusions):
    for phrase in exclusions:
        string = string.replace(phrase, '')
    return string

string = 'will be in every day for each week'
lst = ['for','and','with','be in']
exclusions = ['for every','for each']
replaced = string_minus_exclusions(string, exclusions)
if any(word in replaced for word in lst):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see how that will work, although I think it breaks when you set replaced_string = '', so I have changed it to ```replaced_string = string.replace(phrase, '')```

Comment: You're right. I wasn't testing and just defaulted to an empty string. `replaced_string = ''` should be `replaced_string = string`